# vb6 excel late binding

Tags: excel, vba, vb6, powerpoint

I'm using Office 2016 32bits on Win10. The following code worked perfectly and I was able to manage every aspect of Excel and PPT from VB6.

```
   Public Sub Main()
   '*********************BDOK GAM ****************************ú÷åôú 
   Dim xlApp As Object    ' Late binding, or As Excel.Application with Early
    Public PpApp As Object    ' Late binding, or As Excel.Application with Early

On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set PpApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
```

But now, in the last few days, xlApp and PpApp return "nothing" and I have not a clue why? Excel and Powerpoint are properly referenced

**When using the same code In VBA module, it works fine**

Comment: Are the Excel and PPT applications already open when you run your code?

Comment: Yes  Excel and PPT applications already open

Comment: If you comment out the `On Error Resume Next` do you get any error ?

Comment: "Activex component can't create object"

Comment: Maybe your office (or maybe your antivirus) was updated?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the component MSCOMCTL.OCX was unable to register properly causing a lot of issues. I managed to correct that and now the late binding works properly